# Regarding CommunitiesSelfRegController Salesforce communities

Tags: community, customer-community, self-registration

I am trying to figure out a way to change the logic in default CommunitiesSelfRegController controller for user self registration via community. 
My use case is to create a new account everytime when a user is created via community. Can anyone please help me to achieve the same.

```
    /**
 * An apex page controller that supports self registration of users in communities that allow self registration
 */
public class CommunitiesSelfRegController {

    public String firstName {get; set;}
    public String lastName {get; set;}
    public String email {get; set;}
    public String password {get; set {password = value == null ? value : value.trim(); } }
    public String confirmPassword {get; set { confirmPassword = value == null ? value : value.trim(); } }
    public String communityNickname {get; set { communityNickname = value == null ? value : value.trim(); } }

    public CommunitiesSelfRegController() {}

    private boolean isValidPassword() {
        return password == confirmPassword;
    }

    public PageReference registerUser() {

           // it's okay if password is null - we'll send the user a random password in that case
        if (!isValidPassword()) {
            ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, Label.site.passwords_dont_match);
            ApexPages.addMessage(msg);
            return null;
        }    

        String profileId = '00e0n000000LvoX'; // To be filled in by customer.
        String roleEnum = null; // To be filled in by customer.
         // To be filled in by customer.

        Account Acc = new account();
        Acc.name = firstname + lastname;
        insert Acc;

        Contact c = new contact (Lastname = lastname);
        c.accountid = Acc.id;
        insert c;

        String accountId = Acc.id;
        String userName = email;

        User u = new User();
        u.Username = userName;
        u.Email = email;
        u.FirstName = firstName;
        u.LastName = lastName;
        u.CommunityNickname = communityNickname;
        u.ProfileId = profileId;

        String userId;

        try {
            userId = Site.createExternalUser(u, accountId, password);
        } catch(Site.ExternalUserCreateException ex) {
            List<String> errors = ex.getDisplayMessages();
            for (String error : errors)  {
                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, error));
            }

            // This message is used for debugging. Do not display this in the UI to the end user.
            // It has the information around why the user creation failed.
            System.debug(ex.getMessage());
        }

        if (userId != null) { 
            if (password != null && password.length() > 1) {
                return Site.login(userName, password, ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('startURL'));
            }
            else {
                PageReference page = System.Page.CommunitiesSelfRegConfirm;
                page.setRedirect(true);
                return page;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have added code to create a new account every time. What is the error/problem you are facing?

Comment: Yes. I have added the code but the controller some how is not creating the new account and mapping the newly registered contact under the same account(This is the default functionality of the controller as the person account is not enabled in my org). Not sure if there is any setting which i am missing. Can you please help.

Comment: Can you increase logs and see if there is a exception or till which step your code is executing successfully.

Comment: Actually i tired to add Guest user to debug log but sf is not generating any logs for the guest user. Not sure if i am missing something.

Comment: Old thread but for anyone stumbling across this: you have to set the trace on the user specified in Administration -> Login and Registration 0>  Execute Registration As, not the guest user.